# Facebook account already linked to another steam profile

Tags: steam

I have created a new Steam account and made new purchases. The problem is, I can't link my Facebook account to it because it has already been linked to another Steam account.

I don't remember anything about my previous Steam account, so I am unable to unlink the Facebook account.

Is there any fix for this type of issue? I have already tried Steam support.

Answer (score 2):

You can unlink the account's via Facebook

1. Login to Facebook
2. Go to your Facebook settings.
3. Once in settings click the Apps section on the left hand side column
   [image]
4. Find steam, hover over it and click the 'x' beside it and remove app.
5. Now you can link your new Steam account to your Facebook.

Comment: If you can't find the Steam app on Facebook, it may be in the "Expired" section.